# converting php mysql time to seconds ago

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

im having a problem converting time. for some reason it seems to be defaulting back to 1970 which i believe is unix default time. im using this code, when i run the program i get 42years instead of 2 years. what am i missing. please help
 here is the code

```
<?php

  function convertime($ptime) {
        $etime = time() - $ptime;

        if($etime < 60) {
                return 'less than minute ag';
        }

        $a = array(12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 => 'year', 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 => 'month', 24 * 60 * 60 => 'day', 60 * 60 => 'hour', 60 => 'minute' //  1                       =>  'second'
                );

        foreach($a as $secs => $str) {
                $d = $etime / $secs;
                if($d >= 1) {
                        $r = round($d);
                        return $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '');
                }
        }
  }

?>

<?php

  $ctime = 2009-02-23 10:09:00 //time from mysql
        echo convertime($ctime);

?>
```

Comment: Are you passing literally `2009-02-23 10:09:00` to your function? If so, wrap `strtotime()` around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap `strtotime()` around your timestamp:

```
$ctime = strtotime('2009-02-23 10:09:00'); //time from mysql
```

http://codepad.org/HWQrLwBy

You need to compare a timestamp to a timestamp.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Feel free to up vote too... `:D`

Comment: one quick question, why does it say 3 years and  not 2

Comment: Let me look at it; I would imagine it's because your comparison `foreach` loop isn't working as expected.

Comment: Try this: http://codepad.org/uMAtwmEs I think it's because you were using `round()` instead of `floor()`, which was rounding up. See the array result, BTW.

Comment: @user836910 - Are you serious? You're going to select the other answer as the correct answer? (You can only have one, btw.)

Comment: @user836910 - Note, the more precise parts of the time aren't correct. I'm looking into this, see if I can improve it.

Comment: @user836910 - I can get it [this close](http://codepad.org/mPvnuAnD), but my brain is not cooperating (it's late here). Try opening another question on why your for loop isn't working. Sorry.

Comment: @user836910 - The weird thing is the minute's don't seem to be converting correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

  function convertime($ptime) {
        $etime = time() - $ptime;

        if($etime < 60) {
                return 'less than minute ag';
        }

        $a = array(12 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 => 'year', 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 => 'month', 24 * 60 * 60 => 'day', 60 * 60 => 'hour', 60 => 'minute' //  1                       =>  'second'
                );

        foreach($a as $secs => $str) {
                $d = $etime / $secs;
                if($d >= 1) {
                        $r = round($d);
                        return $r . ' ' . $str . ($r > 1 ? 's' : '');
                }
        }
  }

?>

<?php

  $ctime = strtotime('2009-02-23 10:09:00'); //time from mysql
  echo convertime($ctime);

?>
```

try it